# Roller coaster physics

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, centripetal-force

I am trying to figure out how to calculate the $g$-forces throughout a non-uniform corkscrew as well as the exiting velocity.

Do you calculate each radius separately and each $g$-force separately for each change?

Answer (score 2):

For a general curve $y(x)$ in Cartesian coordinates, the radius $r$ of curvature is given by:

$$r=|\frac{(1+\dot y^2)^{3/2}}{\ddot y}|,$$

where $\dot y=\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $\ddot y=\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$.

In:

$$F=m\frac{v^2}{r},$$

$r$ must then be inserted for each value of $x$, as calculated above. The force $F$ will then vary in different parts of the bend, unless the bend is part of a circle (arc), because then $r$ is constant.

Comment: The bend is part of a circle, but I am trying to find the acceleration and to do that I need to find velocity, which I am confused about how to find and how it would factor into the overall decreasing radii corkscrew.

Comment: @ChristineC: this problem is impossible to solve without a full geometrical description. From it the equation(s) of motion can then be set up.

Comment: @ChristineC since gravity is the only force acting on the coaster (I'm assuming you are neglecting friction or using an after-the-fact approximation on it), the velocity is only a function of height.

Answer (score -1):

What is your starting condition? Is the form of the non-uniform corkscrew given?

In general you can calculate the force that keeps your vehicle in track:

$F=m\frac{v^2}{r}$

where v is the speed of the vehicle, and r is the radius of the curve. The acceleration ("g"-value) is:
$a=\frac{v^2}{r}$
You might want to add/substract the earth's gravitation (attention: these are vectors). If the roller-coster runs at a constant speed, the answer is easy.

Comment: What roller coaster _ever_ runs at a constant speed?  Look up the word "coast."

Comment: The starting conditions and form are not given, I am allowed to make it however I would like as long as it is a corkscrew that has two to three different radius sizes (decreasing). I have the above equation but I am attempted to calculate for velocity so I can use the above equation. I found this equation: v= (2*pi*r)/time but is r supposed to be the arc of the curve or the radius of the corkscrew. If I do that will I then treat each section of the corkscrew as a separate problem to solve?